# Free up a partition for installing another OS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, multi-boot

I have 1TB hard disk in total which is fully used:

[image: fully used disk]

Now, for some reasons I need to install [Ubuntu 14.4 OS](http://www.ubuntu.com/) (dual booted) on the same computer.

I have deleted everything from partition **F:** so, it shall not be in **use**.

[image: deleted everything from partition F:]

I wanted to use this **207.80 GB** for Ubuntu.

**Problem:**

I am not able to use **Delete Volume** feature:

[image: unable to delete volume]

If I cannot delete a volume, how do I make space and subsequently install another OS on the same computer?

Comment: Use Easeus partition manager, or partition wizard. You boot into them

Comment: @barlop What is partition wizard?

Comment: try typing partition wizard into google, and the entire first page of google gives you links to it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the partition **F:** is marked as **System Partition** which I think is your current Windows-7 installation drive. You can not remove a partition while its in use, in this case your Windows is running and all critical system files are in use. You can either use some Live bootable Media or Windows Installation drive to delete and create partitions.

Comment: **F:** is blank so it must not be in use.